# How to read a file in c using NDK in android

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I am trying to read a file in c using NDK. When i debug the code, i see that i get a NULL pointer in f(file reading pointer). Also, my file which i need to read is in the same folder under cpp including all other header files. I have the read and write permissions for external storage in my app. Any help is appreciated.

C Code:

```js
#ifndef client_h
#define client_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "utility.h"


#define SENDBUFSIZE 1399
#define RECVBUFSIZE 1399

void pingServer(char *hostname, int portno)
{
  //Some other functionality which works correctly


  // File Read operations
  FILE *f = fopen("somefile.csv", "r"); //Get the null pointer here
  if (f == NULL)
    perror("Could not open input file");
  char *currentRow[3];
  char *nextRow[3];
  int rows = 3;

  for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
  {
    currentRow[i] = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
    nextRow[i] = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
  }
  double current, next;
  double elapsed;
  int isNextRow, isCurentRow;
  readCsvLine(f,currentRow,rows); //Get the headers
  int counter = 2;
  isCurentRow = readCsvLine(f,currentRow,rows);

  //sends the data

  //Free the memory
  for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
  {
    free(currentRow[i]);
    free(nextRow[i]);
  }
  free(buf);
  return;

}

char* printName(){
    char* ptr = "hello From C";
    return ptr;
}

#endif
```

Java code for calling the c methods:

```js
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include "client.h"

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_habbas_mobiledifferentiation_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    char *hostname = "127.0.0.1";
    int portno = 1254;
    pingServer(hostname, portno);
    std::string hello = printName();
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

Comment: `my file which i need to read is in the same folder under cpp including all other header files.` So your file is on your development pc. Why do you think an app on your Android device has acces to files on your pc?

Comment: Its under cpp folder; which means it should be able to read the file since my all c source files are there. If not then please suggest how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: The cpp folder is on your development pc isnt it? My question is the same.

Comment: Yes it is on my development pc.

Comment: Indeed. The file is on your development pc. Not on your Android device.

Comment: Any work around to this; where should i put the file(android device) such that it could be read by the c code.

Comment: `I have the read and write permissions for external storage in my app.`. Then i would think you put your file in external storage. Use full path for fopen(). Only a file name will not do.

Comment: `Java code for calling the c methods:`. That does not look like java code.

Comment: @greenapps it looks like C++ code with `extern C`

Comment: It is the c/c++ code that declares that inline function. But not the java code that calls it. Please show that java code.